# Is this ASP.Net view code effecient?

Tags: asp.net

I have the code in my activities.cshtml view to display events of the view model as follows:

```
        <ul>
            @foreach (var activity in Model.Items)
            {
                <li>@activity.StartDateTime</li>
                <li>@activity.CampaignName</li>
                <li>@activity.Title</li>
                @foreach (var Task in activity.Tasks)
                {
                    <p><em>@Task.Name</em></p>
                }
            }
        </ul>
```

Whenever there is a loop within a loop, there should be a more efficient. However, I'm not aware of any way to do this within the view model.

Comment: There is no way to accomplish this without a loop within a loop.  However, there are more appropriate ways to handle this situation in MVC.  You should be using Editor or DisplayTemplates.  These will still perform loops internally, but they are more manageable and maintainable.